# how to search data if user enter in any of the fields in the form in python

Tags: python, cgi

Below cgi script contains the Search criteria in a file. A form has four field Fname, Lname,Age and Gender. If a user enters data in any one field, two field, three field, or four field , it should display the match records. 
How do i obtains that ? for all the fields. How am i suppose to write for all condition

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import cgi


found = False

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
Fname = form.getvalue('firstname', '')
Lname = form.getvalue('lastname', '')
Age = form.getvalue('age', 0)
Gender = form.getvalue('gender', '')
fname = "/tmp/myfile.txt"

print "Content-type:text/html\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2><b><i>Search Data</i></b></h2>"
print "<table cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2' border='1'>"
print "<br>"
print "<td>First Name</td>"
print "<td>Last Name</td>"
print "<td>Age</td>"
print "<td>Gender</td>"
print "</tr>"


if os.path.exists(fname):

    f = open(fname, "r")

    b = []
    for line in f:
        temp = line.split()
        Fsearch = temp[0]
        Lsearch = temp[1]
        Asearch = temp[2]
        Gsearch = temp[3]



        if Fname and Fname.lower() == Fsearch.lower():
            found = True

        if Lname and Lname.lower() == Lsearch.lower():
            found = True

        if Age and Age == Asearch:
            found = True

        if Gender and Gender == Gsearch :
            found = True

        if found:
            b.append(line)


        found = False

    f.close()

    if len(b) == 0:
        print "<h2>", "No records found","</h2>"

    else:
        for each in b:
            store = each.split()

            print "<tr>"
            print "<td>", store[0], "</td>"
            print "<td>", store[1], "</td>"
            print "<td>", store[2], "</td>"
            print "<td>", store[3], "</td>"
            print "</tr>"


else:
    print "Search Other File"
                                                                                           print "</table>"
print "<br><a href='/~tom/index.html'>Home</a>"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

I have a file like this :

```
Ram Charan 25 male
John Mckay 28 Male
Ashley Lobo 25 Female
Sara jane 28 Female
```

Now my forn ha four field:

```
FirsrName:
Last Name:
Age:
Gender(male Female Radio button)
```

If user enter data in any one field or two field or in all the field, then it should match the data and display the record

For Eg If I enter:

```
Firstname: 
lastName:
Age: 25
Gender: Male (radio button)
```

It should display the record of the male who is 25 year old and Male

if user enter data in any three field as:

```
FirstName: Ashley
Lastname: 
Age: 25
Gender: Female (radio button)
```

it should display the matched records.

Similarly if user enter data in all field and like wise

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you show what the input should be like, the expected output, and the current output?

Comment: Updated Description. Please let me know. i am really confused